# Сортировка Collections.sort() и замер времени выполнения

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь замерить время для сортировки в одинаковых условиях для LinkedList & ArrayList.

```
public static long test(List<Integer> list, int reps) {
    List<Integer> copy = list;
    long begin = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = 0; i < reps; i++) {
        Collections.sort(list);
        list = copy;
    }
    long end = System.nanoTime();
    return (end - begin) / reps;
}
```

Array List:  50241 ns

Linked List: 109349 ns

Array List:  22740 ns

Linked List: 37354 ns

Array List:  36633 ns

Linked List: 45177 ns

Сортировка идёт за log(n), но у меня при трех повторениях выдаёт, что LinkedList сортируется в 2-3 раза медленнее (очень редко приблизительно одинаково). Вообще, замеряет как будто рандомно, не могу понять почему такой разброс замеров.

Comment: Написать правильный бенчмарк для Java чертовски сложно, так как внутри JVM происходит множество процессов, скрытых от вас, но способных влиять на замеры как в положительную, так в отрицательную сторону.

Comment: @Roydgar Также добавлю, что в java присваивание объектов происходит по ссылке, поэтому `copy` и `list` всегда представляют один и тот же объект, поэтому на каждой итерации, кроме первой, выполняется сортировка уже отсортированного массива

Comment: Обязательно послушайте [Алексея Шипилёва про бенчмарки](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8pMfUopQ9Es)

Comment: оу, спасибо, порой такие глупые и очевидные ошибки :( Спасибо за информацию про бенчмарки)

Answer (score 3):

[Use the Source, Luke](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Use%20the%20Source%2C%20Luke) - иными словами смотрите исходные тексты.

Итак всматриваемся и видим, что [исходники ArrayList](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java) показывают, что это всего лишь обертка над `Object[]`

Далее, давайте заглянем в [исходники LinkedList](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/LinkedList.java#LinkedList.Entry) - видим, что это обертка над структурой типа двунаправленный список:

```
 private static class Entry<E> {
   E element; //собственно сам элемент
   Entry<E> next;  //указатель на следующий элемент
   Entry<E> previous;  //указатель на следующий элемент
   //blah-blah
 }
```

Обертка собственно говоря содержит только указатель на голову такого списка `header`, далее если надо позиционироваться на нужный элемент то надо пройтись по списку от начала до конца: `header.next()` и так `n` раз - в случае же `ArrayList` - позиционирование производится практически мгновенно по индексу массива.

Вот собственно говоря и все - сортировка предусматривает активные операции по позиционированию в списке/массиве, соответственно, в случае `LinkedList` - это выливается в нудные последовательные перемещения вдоль списка, а `ArrayList` - как бы устройство с прямым доступом.

Comment: [`Collections.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)) предварительно сливает список в массив, т.е. разница есть, но сложность алгоритма не изменяется для `LinkedList`

Comment: Согласен, правда ваша